# Can't scrape same part of a page with the only difference being div and span

Tags: python, lxml

I'm currently trying to learn to scrape, therefore i'm trying to scrape futbin for FIFA player stats. I'm working at [this link](https://www.futbin.com/19/player/19/Gary%20Lineker/) of Gary Lineker now (for example). When I try to scrape his stats (say acceleration for example). It only works with the number, not the actual text.

These two works together and forms a list with the stats.

```
stats = doc.xpath('//*[@class="stat_val"]/text()')

<div class="stat_val">90</div>
```

However, these two creates nothing, just an empty list.

```
statNames = doc.xpath('//span[@class="ig-stat-name-tooltip tooltipstered"]/text()')

<span class="ig-stat-name-tooltip tooltipstered">Acceleration</span>
```

Both are in the same group so to speak. This is the full code:

```
<div class=" row_sep sub_stat">
    <div class="stat_holder_sub  left_stat_name" style="display: inline-block;">
        <span class="ig-stat-name-tooltip tooltipstered">Acceleration</span>
    </div>
    <div id="sub-acceleration-val-0" class="stat_val  acceleration-val-0 stat_text_dark_green" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="stat_diff" style=" display: inline-block;"></div>
        <div class="stat_diff_cards" style=" display: none;"></div>
        <div class="stat_val">90</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the actual difference? Shouldn't both work like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you omit `tooltipstered` from the xpath, such as in the following code, you'll get the results you were looking for:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'https://www.futbin.com/19/player/19/Gary%20Lineker/'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
statNames = tree.xpath('//*[@class="ig-stat-name-tooltip"]/text()')

print([res for res in statNames])
```

Result:

```
['Pace', 'Acceleration', 'Sprint Speed', 'Shooting', 'Positioning', 'Finishing', 'Shot Power', 'Long Shots', 'Volleys', 'Penalties', 'Passing', 'Vision', 'Crossing', 'FK. Accuracy', 'Short Passing', 'Long Passing', 'Curve', 'Dribbling', 'Agility', 'Balance', 'Reactions', 'Ball Control', 'Dribbling', 'Composure', 'Defending', 'Interceptions', 'Heading Accuracy', 'Marking', 'Standing Tackle', 'Sliding Tackle', 'Physicality', 'Jumping', 'Stamina', 'Strength', 'Aggression']
```